# función undefined JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, function, base64, undefined

Buen dia,

Tengo un tema, tengo una función que pasa una imagen a BASE64, la función servia bien, pero sin razón dejo de funcionar, no tiene logica ya que mi sintaxis es correcta, comparto mi código HTML y JS.

Paso mi imagen a base64 porque mando todo en un JSON, mi formulario y mi servico

JS

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#enviar").on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                createProduct();
            });

            function createProduct() {
                var urlswProd = "miUrlWebService";

                var sProduct1 = document.querySelector('#sProduct').value;
                var imageProduct = imagetoB64();

                console.log(imageProduct);
                var jnAddProduct = {
 
                    subCategory: sProduct1,
                    image: imageProduct
                };

                function imagetoB64() {
                    var picture = document.querySelector('#imageBrowse').files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function () {
                        var image64 = reader.result;
                        var block = image64.split(',');
                        image64 = block[1];
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(picture);
                };

            }
        });
```

CODIGO HTML

```html
<div>
<label>Imagen:</label>
<input id="imageBrowse" class="boton" name="imagen" type="file">
</div>
```

Comment: la variable **imageProduct** me marca undefined

Comment: Puede ser que cambiaste de lugar a la imagen y ya no se encuentra en la posición [0].

Comment: Si imprimo un consolé.log dentro de la función reader.onloadend , si me arroja el bade64

Comment: Falta HTML por que no sé que es esto "#sProduct" y "#enviar"

Comment: No deberías retornar image64 ?

Comment: Le agregué return y aún no me funciona :s

Comment: por qué no usas el depurador de chrome para ver qué pasa dentro de imagetoB64()?

Comment: esto es lo que me arroja el depurador de chrom   **Return value: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQY...**
aun asi sigue undefined mi variable